# How Cythonize Function With Input Being List Of Dicts

Tags: python, cython

I have a Python input that looks something like:

```
inters = [{"id": "sku0", "items": ["sku0", "sku1"], "scores": [0.9, 0.3]},
          {"id": "sku1", "items": ["sku0", "sku2", "sku3"], "scores": [0.1, 0.8, 0.2]}, ...]
```

And a dict with weights:

```
weights = {"sku0": 0.5, "sku1": 2., (...)}
```

I'm looking for a way to cythonize the following operation: for each dict in `inters`, multiply each value in  `scores` by the correspondent value of `id` in `weights` and then sum the result to a final dict, whose key is the value in `items`.

To better illustrate, I tried implementing this in Cython:

[image]

For each dict, I get each value in `scores` multiplied by `scores[id]` and add to a final `res` dict.

This already made the code **7x** faster than original Python implementation (implemeted like):

```
from collections import Counter
def make_recos(inters, scores):                                               
    r = sum([Counter({e['items'][i]: e['scores'][i] * scores[e['id']] for i in range(len(e['items']))}) for e in inters], Counter())
```

We still need it to be faster. From what the Cython annotation tells, there's still lots of Python-API calls (specially line `14`) that I don't know how to avoid doing given that values inside the keys of the dictionaries are not C structures but rather Python objects yet.

Is there some way of making these values inside each dict a C structure so to avoid the Python calls? Or maybe some other strategy to make the Cython code faster?

Comment: I don't think Cython can help you too much if you want to use dicts and lists. I can only see minor changes (`internsi=interns[i]` since you use it multiple times; replace your if with `res.setdefault(sku,0.0)`).

Comment: This does look like something that you _might_ be able to rewrite efficiently using pandas though. Although it isn't entirely straightforward so it's hard to know how fast it'll be.

Comment: Thanks David for the comments. After reading it I'm trying now sending to cython a list of strings with all these information, something like ["sku0",  "3", "sku0,sku1,sku2", "0.1,0.9,0.8"] but still coudn't find a way to make cython know beforehand it's a list of strings. Do you know if it's possible? I tried with `process_scores(char **input)` or `(array.array input)` but still the python lookups happen.

Comment: Unfortunately no. Cython always treats lists as if they could be any type. Cython is really designed to optimize numeric stuff, and you struggle get too much benefit from non numeric stuff. You could cast the result of indexing to a string (`cdef str s = array[i]` or `cdef str s = <str>array[i]` - I think the latter version skips type checking) but I doubt it will do too much

Comment: I think you should enumerate your strings from `0...n` and to use these numbers instead of ids. Thus, the result would be no longer a map, but an array of doubles (use `array.array`!) you should also keep your scores as `array.array` of doubles (http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/array.html) That would speed up at least some of operations.

Comment: Actually your `items`-data structure can be seen as a sparse matrix and your operations as matrix-vector product (vector = weight vector). Thus you could leverage the functionality from numpy and this probably cannot be beaten.

Comment: @DavidW Thanks David for your input. I ended up using the code I posted and increased a bit the cpu from our machines, final result worked quite well for us :). If you'd like please write this information as an answer and I'll accept and upvote it so those with the same problem already know what's going on. Thanks!

Comment: @ead thanks for the ideas :)! In fact this is exactly how our system already works in production currently and the reason we've been trying to chythonize it is to avoid the management of indices and the skus (in production this turned out to be a nightmare, each time the system updates we have to manage millions of indices properly). With this cython solution it's much simpler as we don't have to make this mapping.